# script to open and download each page of a web-site?

Tags: web, download, wiki, wget

There's a very powerful CLI tool - `wget`. But it seems like it is bad for downloading wikis - where it download the whole database - instead of just downloading current versions of all articles... Perphaps there's a script (python or perl) to load each page of a given web-site in a browser - and download it.

Comment: So I've downloaded a wiki with default webhttrack options. It seems that it did not dowload all the revisions - as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com).

It can be called via command-line as well as via GUI. It's a feature-rich product. They have user guide for both [command-line](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html) and [GUI](http://www.httrack.com/html/shelldoc.html) usage.

Comment: Thanks I'm studying HTTrack now - will try to download a wiki with it. I'll leave the question open for some time anyway - in order to collect various solutions.

Comment: Not a problem. I have used HTTrack for years, and has produced the needed results. Important thing is we can customize it to get exactly what we need.